# Earth Engine: supervised classification from 'stacked' images

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am relatively new to earth engine (8 months), so please excuse me if my questions are obvious. I am trying to run a svm supervised classification of land use using a 'stack' of images. In R I would re-sample the rasters and create a stack to run the algorithm. I more or less tried to take the same approach. Here is the problem:

If i set the scale to a useful resolution (<30m) it returns an error that the remote request was too large or I get 'computation timed out'. If I change the scale to >1000m, the analysis runs, bu the resolution is too coarse to be useful.

Here is the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/211c34da7ad89f555f127167f3f1c15d) to the code.

I have also included it below.

```
var sen2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');

// 1. True color composite
var que = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1ZmXCjXYCmGQLkQbue91s9W2b6q2o_b6OTuRdm5EI');
//Map.addLayer(que);

var s2f_01 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(01,01,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      });

print(s2f_01);

var s2f_01M = s2f_01.mean();

var s2f_02 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(02,02,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_02M = s2f_02.mean();

var s2f_03 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(03,03,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_03M = s2f_03.mean();

var s2f_04 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(04,04,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_04M = s2f_04.mean();

var s2f_05 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(05,05,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_05M = s2f_05.mean();

var s2f_06 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(06,06,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_06M = s2f_06.mean();

var s2f_07 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(07,07,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_07M = s2f_07.mean();

// var s2f_08 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
//       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(08,08,'month'))
//       .filterBounds(que)
//       .map(function (image){
//         return image.clip(que);
//       }); 

// var s2f_08M = s2f_08.mean();

// var s2f_09 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
//       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(09,09,'month'))
//       .filterBounds(que)
//       .map(function (image){
//         return image.clip(que);
//       }); 

// var s2f_09M = s2f_09.mean();

var s2f_10 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10,10,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_10M = s2f_10.mean();

var s2f_11 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(11,11,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_11M = s2f_11.mean();

var s2f_12 = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2018, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(12,12,'month'))
      .filterBounds(que)
      .map(function (image){
        return image.clip(que);
      }); 

var s2f_12M = s2f_12.mean();

var lt_dst = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1");

// Use ee.Filter.calendarRange to filter by year and month
// 6.1 December
var dst_lt_12 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(12,12,'month'))
    .filterBounds(que)
    .map(function(image){
    return image.clip(que);
});

// reduce image collection with mean()
var dst_lt_12M = dst_lt_12.mean();

// 6.12 November
var dst_lt_11 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(11,11,'month'))
    .filterBounds(que)
    .map(function(image){
    return image.clip(que);
});

// reduce image collection with mean()
var dst_lt_11M = dst_lt_11.mean();

// 6.3 October
var dst_lt_10 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10,10,'month'))
    .filterBounds(que)
    .map(function(image){
    return image.clip(que);
});

// reduce image collection with mean()
var dst_lt_10M = dst_lt_10.mean();

// // 6.4 September
// var dst_lt_09 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
//     .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(09,09,'month'))
//     .filterBounds(que)
//     .map(function(image){
//     return image.clip(que);
// });

// // reduce image collection with mean()
// var dst_lt_09M = dst_lt_09.mean();

// // 6.5 August
// var dst_lt_08 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2002,2018,'year'))
//     .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(08,08,'month'))
//     .filterBounds(que)
//     .map(function(image){
//     return image.clip(que);
// });

// // reduce image collection with mean()
// var dst_lt_08M = dst_lt_08.mean();

// 6.6 July
var dst_lt_07 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(07,07,'month'))
    .filterBounds(que)
    .map(function(image){
    return image.clip(que);
});

// reduce image collection with mean()
var dst_lt_07M = dst_lt_07.mean();

// 6.7 June
var dst_lt_06 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(06,06,'month'))
    .filterBounds(que)
    .map(function(image){
    return image.clip(que);
});

// reduce image collection with mean()
var dst_lt_06M = dst_lt_06.mean();

// 6.8 May
var dst_lt_05 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(05,05,'month'))
    .filterBounds(que)
    .map(function(image){
    return image.clip(que);
});

// reduce image collection with mean()
var dst_lt_05M = dst_lt_05.mean();

// 6.9 April
var dst_lt_04 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(04,04,'month'))
    .filterBounds(que)
    .map(function(image){
    return image.clip(que);
});

// reduce image collection with mean()
var dst_lt_04M = dst_lt_04.mean();

// 6.10 March
var dst_lt_03 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(03,03,'month'))
    .filterBounds(que)
    .map(function(image){
    return image.clip(que);
});

// reduce image collection with mean()
var dst_lt_03M = dst_lt_03.mean();

// 6.11 Feb
var dst_lt_02 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(02,22,'month'))
    .filterBounds(que)
    .map(function(image){
    return image.clip(que);
});

// reduce image collection with mean()
var dst_lt_02M = dst_lt_02.mean();

// 6.11 Jan
var dst_lt_01 = lt_dst.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2001,2018,'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(01,01,'month'))
    .filterBounds(que)
    .map(function(image){
    return image.clip(que);
});

// reduce image collection with mean()
var dst_lt_01M = dst_lt_01.mean();

Map.setCenter(-98.9, 20.8, 7);

var s2f = sen2.filterDate('2019-02-01', '2019-02-15');

var median = s2f.median();

var clipped = median.clipToCollection(que);


var trueColor = {
    bands: ["B4", "B3", "B2"],
    min: 0,
    max: 3000
  };

Map.addLayer(clipped, trueColor, 'clipped composite');
print(clipped);

// NDVI = (NIR - RED)/(NIR + RED)
// Define variable NDVI from equation
var NDVI = clipped.expression(
    "(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)",
    {
      RED: clipped.select("B4"),    // RED
      NIR: clipped.select("B8"),    // NIR
      BLUE: clipped.select("B2")    // BLUE
    });

//Map.addLayer(NDVI, {min: 0, max: 1}, "NDVI");
print(NDVI);

var falseColor = {
      bands: ["B8", "B4", "B3"],
      min: 0,
      max: 3000
  };

Map.addLayer(clipped, falseColor, 'false color composite');

var dem = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');
var dem_clipped = dem.clip(que);
var elevation = dem_clipped.select('elevation');
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation);
//Map.addLayer(slope, {min: 0, max: 60}, 'slope');
print(slope);

var newfc = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(crop_lands, {'land_use': 0}),
  ee.Feature(urban_areas, {'land_use': 1}),
  ee.Feature(uncultivated, {'land_use': 2}),
  ee.Feature(water, {'land_use': 3}),
]);

print(newfc);

var stack = clipped.addBands(NDVI)
                      .addBands(slope)
                      .addBands(s2f_01M)
                      .addBands(s2f_02M)
                      .addBands(s2f_03M)
                      .addBands(s2f_04M)
                      .addBands(s2f_05M)
                      .addBands(s2f_06M)
                      .addBands(s2f_07M)
                      .addBands(s2f_10M)
                      .addBands(s2f_11M)
                      .addBands(s2f_12M)
                      .addBands(dst_lt_01M)
                      .addBands(dst_lt_02M)
                      .addBands(dst_lt_03M)
                      .addBands(dst_lt_04M)
                      .addBands(dst_lt_05M)
                      .addBands(dst_lt_06M)
                      .addBands(dst_lt_07M)
                      .addBands(dst_lt_10M)
                      .addBands(dst_lt_11M)
                      .addBands(dst_lt_12M);


print(stack);

var bands = ['B4', 'B8', 'B2', 'B3', 
            'slope', 
            'LST_Day_1km', 'QC_Day', 'Day_view_time', 'Day_view_angle', 'LST_Night_1km', 'QC_Night', 'Night_view_time', 'Night_view_angle', 'Emis_31', 'Emis_32', 'Clear_day_cov', 'Clear_night_cov'];

// // First interation of creating the training data
var training = stack.sampleRegions({
  collection: newfc,
  properties: ['land_use'],
  scale: 30,
  tileScale: 16
});


var classifier = ee.Classifier.svm({
  kernelType: 'RBF',
  gamma: 0.5,
  cost: 10
});

var trained = classifier.train(training, 'land_use', bands);

print(training.first());

// Classify the image.
var classified = stack.classify(trained);

var landusePallet = [
  'C0C0C0', // urban_areas
  '0000FF', // water
  'FFFF00', // crop_lands
  '008000', // uncultivated
  ];

// Display the classification result and the input image.
Map.setCenter(-98.9, 20.8, 7);
Map.addLayer(stack, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.5, gamma: 2});
Map.addLayer(newfc, {}, 'training data');
Map.addLayer(classified,
            {min: 0, max: 1, palette: landusePallet},
            'land use');
```

Comment: You might try saving your `stack` image as an asset (`Export.image.toAsset`), then in a separate script, import the asset and do the sampling and classifying from it. Also, you can condense much of your code by mapping the mean month compositing over a month List. Here is an example for generating `dst_lt_XXX` images as a band stack. https://code.earthengine.google.com/5fb57247a478ed71069e75ab419035d7